# text inside div element not being printed out with Beautifulsoup and requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to code a script to scrape an ebay listing but I am encountering issues scraping the description and storing it in a variable. This is only the relevant parts of my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

item = '293716122560'
url = 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/' + item
result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')

description = soup.find(id="ds_div")
print(description)
```

However, my output is this:

```
None
```

As you can see, not very useful. I have tried to solve this for ages but I have figured it is something to do with how the html is structured. Can anybody do some testing and give me a hand, would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There is no `ds_div` tag in your url, so none is found...

Comment: there is when I check the code

Comment: Try it yourself, go to the URL, go in inspect element, and click on the description

Comment: I tried and didn't find it.....

Comment: do you have a discord we can talk on, I can clearly see it on an incognito chrome window

Comment: I can send u screenshots on discord

Comment: no discord, sorry...however you can add the debug steps you are following on the question, maybe we can help. I guess you're not using bs in the correct way...

Answer (score -1):

It looks like that element gets rendered with JavaScript so requests won't see it. You can use Selenium instead of requests to get it: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/.

Comment: I figured it out, it is inside an iframe